# Get child node using self id

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to get child node of an xml. I have an attribute named "id" in my parent node. Here's the xml contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<languages>
    <item id="button_back">
        <turkish>geri</turkish>
        <english>back</english>
    </item>
    <item id="button_install">
        <turkish>seçilileri kur</turkish>
        <english>install selected</english>
    </item>
</languages>
```

Say I want to get value of turkish tag. How can I do this? Here's what I tried:

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(@"languages.xml"))
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);
    var query = from t in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                where t.Element("id").Value.ToLower() == "button_back" // Edit
                select new
                {
                    ID = t.Attribute("id").Value,
                    Turkish = t.Element("turkish").Value
                };

    foreach (var it in query)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(it.Turkish);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** This code is giving me null reference exception for <strike>xr</strike> line with MessageBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException` there, because you're assuming `Element("id")` is not null. And it will be, because you have no id element. You need to use `Attribute("id")`.

Comment: @OnurCan upvoting the answer is one concrete way to express the words 'thanks a lot'. So that should be the first action to do before saying 'thanks a lot'. Of course you might not know about voting system in SO, so now you should know that.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this using xml linq with a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("item")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("id"), y => (string)y.Element("turkish"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I don't want to use XDocument because I got a warning telling me XDocument won't be used in newer versions.

Comment: @OnurCan really? actually you used XDocument in your code. Where did you find the warning about that? `XDocument` is one part building the so-called LINQ-To-XML, if it went away, LINQ-To-XML would also go away. That's unbelievable because linq-to-xml is really helpful.

Comment: XDocument is the new version of XmlDocument, but both are used in millions of applications and will never go away.